# How to prevent SharePoint 2010 Ribbon from reformating HTML code

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, formatting

I have the telerik editor installed in SharePoint 2010 Enterprise, and every time I edit a page in advance HTML mode, I would like SharePoint to remember how I formated the HTML code.  But instead, after hitting ok and publishing the page, and then going back to edit the HTML code, SharePoint reformats the entire code layout I just put in.  Sense the HTML code is being stored into a SharePoint Database location, I am betting this is more of a SharePoint setting, rather than a telerik editor setting.

Is there a way to tell the SharePoint Ribbon to disable re-formatting of HTML code?

Formatting options?

Thanks!